# Change url by htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove the .php extension from the url by htaccess file . please let me know How can I do it ??

```
  url:http://domain name/profile.php
```

I want like this

```
  url:http://domain name/profile
```

Comment: This has been answered probably 20,000 times here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on it in order to be able to write regular expressions and use .htaccess in different ways, but a simple rewrite would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^profile$ profile.php [L]
```

If you wanted to globally remove all of .php extensions but retain the filename, you'd need a regex that looked something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+).php$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: You need to be sure that Apache is set up correctly with mod_rewrite installed etc.